# Expo - 'eas update' not working - changes are not reflected to installed apps

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, eas

I am trying to push app update using `eas update` but the update is published but I donot see any changes in app even after force stopping and restarting app. I have not published the app on appstore or google playstore is it required to publish app there and then this will work? Because in earlier expo version we could use expo publish and it will send an OTA update.
`eas.json`:

```
{
  "cli": {"version": ">= 6.0.0"},
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "development"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution":"internal",
      "channel": "preview",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "channel": "production",
      "env": {},
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {"production": {}}
}
```

`app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "construction-app",
    "slug": "construction-app",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "sdkVersion": "49.0.0",
    "runtimeVersion": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.rajdewangon.constructionapp"
    },
    "scheme": "raj-construction-android",
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "updates": {
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/56114473-809a-43ac-b667-8309b9ac88f0"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "expo-updates"
    ],
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "56114473-809a-43ac-b667-8309b9ac88f0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying OTA updates in expo, earlier `expo publish` was used to send OTA updates but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thank you.